# How can I test iOS navigation app in simulator or phone?

Tags: ios, testing, navigation

I'm working on a navigation app. But I've a problem with testing it.

How can I test it in office?

Can I *change iOS's GPS coordinates manually*?

Any solution or app ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch the iOS Simulator. Then, open the iOS Simulator's Debug menu and select Location > then you sen five option.. you can select one for according your testing requirement..

Like : Launch the iOS Simulator. Then, open the iOS Simulator's Debug menu and select Location > Freeway Drive

Comment: Please check my comment on answer above. I know how can I test it for static location. But I need to test location changes.

Answer (score 3):

Launch `simulator`.From `Debug` menu you can select `Location`. Now you have 5 options , you can select whatever you want.For entering `custom location` select `custom Location`.

[image: Location]

For `"I'm walking` effect you can select `city Bicycle Ride, City Run or Freeeway Drive`

Answer (score 0):

When you are running your app in the simulator in the debug area in xcode there is a "simulate location" icon where you can select different city locations. If that is not enough you need to test directly in a device.

Comment: I should test changes, seriously. Because, users marker moving on map. So i need to test it like "I'm walking".